# How to prepare these labels for Keras's Conv2D? ValueError: expected dense_14 to have 4 dimensions

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset of 30 nii images and 30 labels, like these:

```
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
8     1
9     1
10    1
11    1
12    1
13    1
14    1
17    1
18    1
19    1
20    1
21    1
22    1
23    1
24    1
26    2
27    2
28    2
29    2
30    2
```

But when I feed the images and the labels to this network:

```
model_conv2d = Sequential()
model_conv2d.add(Conv2D(32, batch_size=30, kernel_size=(8,6), input_shape=(61, 61, 61)))
model_conv2d.add(MaxPooling2D())
model_conv2d.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(8,6)))
model_conv2d.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_conv2d.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_14 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (25, 2)
```

What should I do? Here's how I prepare my labels:

X_rs = X.reshape(30, -1)

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
binarizer = OneHotEncoder()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_rs)
y_binned = binarizer.fit_transform(y.values.reshape(-1, 1))
X_train = X_scaled[:25, :].reshape(25, 61, 61, 61)
y_train = y_binned[:25]
X_test = X_scaled[25:, :]
y_test = y_binned[25:]
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from the `Dense` layer. You apply the `Dense` without a `Flatten` layer before, so its output shape is (batch_size, 20, 23, 1).

So when you pass `y_train` (or `y_test`) with shape (batch_size, num_labels), the error pops because the output shape of your network is (batch_size, 20, 23, 1).

You should try with:

```py
model_conv2d = Sequential()
model_conv2d.add(Conv2D(32, batch_size=30, kernel_size=(8,6), input_shape=(61, 61, 61)))
model_conv2d.add(MaxPooling2D())
model_conv2d.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(8,6)))
model_conv2d.add(Flatten())
model_conv2d.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_conv2d.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
```